# Poloniex api also taking us to the security check page

Tags: java, web-services, api, poloniex

I have been using this [Java poloniex api](https://github.com/TheCookieLab/poloniex-api-java) project for few months but i am facing some issue from last month. I know this is nothing to do with this project but with Poloniex. And because of the issue i am not able to use this project.

The issue is with the **Security Check**. Earlier, poloniex didn't had this feature and when we hit a url it will directly take us to the respective page. But nowadays it's asking to  complete the security check (some kind of image recognisation). Once completed it's returning some cache. For manual this is fine.

But the issue is, for api calls also, it's asking the same security check. For eg,[public api](https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker) , is taken us to this page instead of returning the values.

[image: Public api security check]

Also, i am getting the same response if i check with other's machine also and this is nothing to do with my poloniex account.

Below is the code that i have tried(need to setup the project from git [TheCookieLab](https://github.com/TheCookieLab/poloniex-api-java) ):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    PoloniexPublicAPIClient bitcoin = new PoloniexPublicAPIClient();
    System.out.println(bitcoin.returnTicker());
}
```

Have attached the response(security check page instead of data).
[resp.txt](https://github.com/TheCookieLab/poloniex-api-java/files/1214347/resp.txt)

1. I would like to know if anyone else faced the same issue and the solution?
2. Is it possible to pass the cache that i got from browser along with the api call?

This is applicable for all the api calls. Kindly refer here for more details about [Poloniex API](https://poloniex.com/support/api/)

I have been stuck here for more than a month. Your time and help are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It was probably temporary security rules to counter a DDOS attack.

You have confirmation in [Why is Poloniex API blocked by CAPTCHA? Expected JSON, but response is HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47957480/why-is-poloniex-api-blocked-by-captcha-expected-json-but-response-is-html/49567269#49567269), @Mehul comment :

> Captcha are also country dependent. If I use a USA proxy and access
>   the API, it works as expected, but for example from India it returns a
>   CATPCHA

It is due to the fact that you sent the request from India Ip range...

You may have to use a VPS or VPN outside India to solve your issue.

Comment: It could be a geoIP security feature, as I assume that you are connecting to Poloniex from an India ISP, you may try over a VPN with a visible IP in US or Euro zone. You may also try to use CURL or python wrapper to double check if your issue is only relative to java

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be fixed now. The returnTicker API works for me, this is part of the response I got:

```
{"BTC_BCN":{"id":7,"last":"0.00000029","lowestAsk":"0.000000‌​30"...
```

Can you please confirm?

Comment: I am still facing the same issue. I believe you have done the security check and tried the ticker. Can you check the same in another browser please?

Comment: No, the security check was not presented to me and I'm really sure that this is the first time I visit that page. Could it be that they have blacklisted you somehow?

Comment: No, I have even checked with my friends and they too facing the issue. For checking the public API, it doesn't dependent on user accounts. Can you open new incognito window and try?

Comment: Okay, but still I am facing the same issue. Earlier it worked for you? Or earlier didn't and now working for you

Comment: It worked all the time. Yesterday, earlier this morning and now.

Comment: Thanks for your help dude. But I am still facing the same issue. Really am struck.